# How can I get Handbrake to find VLC?

Tags: dvd, vlc-media-player, ripping, handbrake

I installed HandBrake 0.9.5 i386 (2011010300) on my old 32-bit Intel Mac, to try ripping a DVD (it's the latest version with a prebuilt x86 binary).  I also had the latest version of VLC installed already.

When I ran HandBrake and tried ripping the DVD, I got an alert:

> **HandBrake could not find VLC or your VLC is incompatible (Note: 32 bit vlc is not compatible with 64 bit HandBrake and vice-versa).**
>
> Please download and install VLC media player if you wish to read encrypted DVDs.
>
> (Cancel Scan) (Attempt Scan Anyway) (Get VLC)

My VLC.app had both x86 and x86-64 binaries in it, so to be safe I downloaded an x86-only VLC 2.0.9 from the VLC webpage, and dropped it in my Applications folder (to replace the old version completely).  I restarted both apps to make sure they'd run, and then tried ripping my DVD in HandBrake again, but got the same alert as before.

The "Get VLC" button just takes me to a download page on videolan.org.

I don't see anything in the HandBrake preferences about telling it where VLC is.

Both HandBrake.app and VLC.app are "Mach-O executable i386" (only), and are in my /Applications folder.  How do I get HandBrake to find VLC?

Answer (score 0):

I've always done the ripping portion with [DVDFab Decrypter](http://www.dvdfab.com/hd-decrypter-for-mac.htm), then the encoding with Handbrake.

This would get you past the VLC dependency error.